# How to create a method that changes what the toString method delivers?

Tags: java, methods, tostring

How to create a method " public void changeDisplay() " that changes what the toString method delivers?

So, to make it clear. Here's an example.

Main method:

```
    sportWatch s = new sportWatch(0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(s);
    s.setHeartRate(91);
    s.changeDisplay();
    System.out.println(s);
```

When prinitng the opject s -> Output:

Time: 0:0:0

Time: 0:0:0

Because of the method toString() in the SportWatch class.

```
public String toString() {
    String secStr = Integer.toString(this.sec);
    String minStr = Integer.toString(this.min);
    String hrStr = Integer.toString(this.hr);
    return "Time: "+ hrStr + ":" + minStr + ":" + secStr ;
}
```

I have no idea how to write a changeDisplay method that switches between the time and the heart rate.

PS. Here's the method for setHeartRate

```
public void setHeartRate(int value) {
    this.heartRate = value;
}
```

The final output should look like this:

Time: 0:0:0

Heart rate: 91

And every time I use the changeDisplay method, it should switch between the Time and the Heart rate.

Comment: That is NOT what `toString` is supposed to be used for. That is what you should write a  `getDisplayString` method for.

Comment: Create a boolean field `displayTime`. Add an if-else-statement inside `toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class, you can create a `boolean` variable which will keep track of the status of display e.g. on `changeDisplay()`, it will set the value to `true` and on `resetDisplay()`, it will set the value to `false`. Now, the `toString()` function can return the value leveraging the value of this variable.

```
class SportWatch {
    // ...Other variables
    private int heartRate;
    private boolean displayHeartRate;

    // ...Constructors and other methods

    public void changeDisplay() {
        displayHeartRate = true;
    }

    public void resetDisplay() {
        displayHeartRate = false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String returnValue = "Time: " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

        // If displayHeartRate is true append the caption and value of heartRate;
        if (displayHeartRate) {
            returnValue += System.lineSeparator() + "Heart rate: " + heartRate;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
SportWatch s = new SportWatch(0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println();
s.setHeartRate(91);
s.changeDisplay();
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println();
//...
s.resetDisplay();
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
Time: 0:0:0

Time: 0:0:0
Heart rate: 91

Time: 0:0:0
```

**Some important points:**

1. You do not need to convert `hr`, `min`, or `sec` to `String` by using `Integer#toString`. When you add a string to an `int`, this conversion happens automatically. Notice this change inside my `toString` implementation shown above.
2. Always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of your class should be `SportWatch` instead of `sportWatch`.

Answer (score 1):

## Flip a boolean as a flag

As [commented by Höhener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458792/how-to-create-a-method-that-changes-what-the-tostring-method-delivers#comment115728251_65458792), create a `boolean` member field on your `SportWatch` class. Use an if-then test to determine whether you return one kind of text or the other, heart-beat or current-time. On every call to your method `getDisplayText`, flip that true/false value while returning the desired text.

If an object of your `SportWatch` may be used across threads, use a member field of type [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). (You’ll also need other changes to make your code thread-safe.)

### Enum rather than boolean

To make your code more self-documenting, use enum objects rather than a mere boolean true/false.

Define an enum `DisplayMode` with two objects named `TIME` and `HEART`.

```
enum DisplayMode { TIME , HEART ; }
```

Replace your boolean member field with a field of type `DisplayMode` named `currentDisplayMode` storing either of the two enum objects. Test for the presence of each enum object to determine which kind of text to return for your `getDisplayText` method.

And of course replace one object with the other on each request, instead of flipping the boolean. Perhaps define a `rotate` method on the enum class to get the next enum object.

Using an enum rather than boolean has another benefit: An enum prepares for the future when you might have additional display modes, more than two.

## `toString` is for programmers and testers, not users

Do not involve an override of `toString` in any of this business logic. Define your `toString` method to return text that makes sense when used for debugging and logging. The `toString` method is not intended to be used in a user-interface.

## *java.time*

Do not reinvent time-keeping. Java has the industry-leading date-time handling framework *java.time*. So use it.

A time-of-day without a date and without a zone/offset is presented by `LocalTime`.

But in a real watch, you would be tracking `Instant` internally. For user-interface, you would apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then you would automatically localize by using the user’s choice of `Locale` with `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`.

All this has been covered many times already on StackmOverflow. So search to learn more.

Comment: Great suggestions! Thanks for your constant endeavour to educate the beginners and helping the seasoned programmers to improve.

Comment: Once you've got that enum, you might as well make it `implements Function<SportWatch, String>`...

Answer (score 0):

I think You should take parameter at toString method.
You can add an enum to determine which format You should use like below.

```
public enum TypeOfSportWatchFormat{
      ToLongString,
      ToShortString
      //add special enums you need
}
```

At your toString method take TypeOfSportWatchFormat parameter

```
public String toString(TypeOfSportWatchFormat format){

   //use if or switch case to return your format
  // i prefer switch for speed
    String secStr = Integer.toString(this.sec);
    String minStr = Integer.toString(this.min);
    String hrStr = Integer.toString(this.hr);
    return "Time: "+ hrStr + ":" + minStr + ":" + secStr ;
}
```